# Testing precedence of resolving addresses from commandline

Tags: command-line, configuration

There was such tool but I cannot remember its name. I needed to configure precedence of addresses by `/etc/gai.conf`. I finally managed to find an error, but for future, what's the name of tool which displays the addresses of hostname as `getaddrinfo(3)` displays it?

Comment: What's the output of getaddrinfo(3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there is a tool `resolveip` for this that comes with MySQL.  It should also be dead-simple to write something with e.g. Python or Perl...